# Problemas con un layout Android xml. El layout monta la toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, xml-schema

Estoy programando una aplicación Android en Java.

Tengo el siguiente layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.geologyapplications.minerals.Ficha"
    android:theme="@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#ffff00"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scr1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txtPregunta"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/resps">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/b"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/c"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/d"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
                </RadioGroup>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/a1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/a2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/b1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/b2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/c1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/c2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ok"
                            android:id="@+id/d1"
                            android:contentDescription="correcta"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/falso"
                            android:id="@+id/d2"
                            android:contentDescription="incorrecta"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/responder"
                        android:id="@+id/responder"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/siguiente"
                        android:id="@+id/siguiente"
                        android:elevation="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,UnusedAttribute"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/finalizar"
                        android:id="@+id/finalizar"
                        android:elevation="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,UnusedAttribute"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

En la clase Java no hago nada especial, cargo la barra superior:

```
public class QuizGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_game);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        toolbar.setBackground(colorDrawable);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//La clase es muy larga para ponerla entera, tiene 400 líneas.
```

En la vista diseño, todo parece correcto, no veo que se monte el scrollview sobre la toolbar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el árbol de etiquetas parece correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al lanzar la actividad, en la parte superior derecha de la toolbar, aparece un recuadro en blanco. Es como si hubiese un linearlayout por debajo de la toolbar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría modifcar el archivo xml para que esto no sucediese y se vea la toolbar entera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé por qué, pero los botones estaban presionando hacia arriba el layout principal (hice pruebas con colores y era el layout entero el que mostraba el recuadro). Quitando el atributo `android:elevation="0dp"`, quitando márgenes y dando un height a los botones arregla el problema.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@string/responder"
    android:id="@+id/responder"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@string/siguiente"
    android:id="@+id/siguiente"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@string/finalizar"
    android:id="@+id/finalizar"/>
```

El LinearLayout ya no monta la toolbar.

[image]